# Meteor Add Users to Form Select

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am a little surprised I am not finding anything out there on this. My question is really 2 parts:

1. Is it possible to generate a form select field (preferably with Autoform) with all of the options being registered users emails or names? If so could anyone please provide an example?
2. Is it possible (again autoform is preferred) to have conditional form field rules. EX: I have a client with multiple locations. One select would be for the client, and depending on what is selected here would populate another select that generates all of this clients locations. Again **ANY** examples would be appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Autoform is awesome work done by aldeed. So much of functionality inside it, it would take some time to read and understand the documentation. I will try to help with an example.

> 1. Is it possible to generate a form select field (preferably with Autoform) with all of the options being registered users emails or names? If so could anyone please provide an example?

```
var myAutoForm = new SimpleSchema({

    "formSelectField": {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            type: "selectize",
            options: function() {
                return collectionName.find({ criteria to get  the registered user names }).map(function(c) {

                    var optionsArray = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                        optionsArray[i] = {}; // creates a new object
                        optionsArray[i].label = c[name][i];
                        optionsArray[i].value = c[name][i];
                    }
                    return optionsArray;
                })[0];
            },
            defaultValue: function() {
                return the default value to be picked on the select dropdown

            },

        }
    },
});
```

> 2. Is it possible (again autoform is preferred) to have conditional form field rules. EX: I have a client with multiple locations. One select would be for the client, and depending on what is selected here would populate another select that generates all of this clients locations. Again ANY examples would be appreciated!

For this, I will put only the options part of the autoform

```
options: function() {
        if(AutoForm.getFieldValue('fieldName', 'formId')==='something')
        })
            return someValue;
    },
```

Comment: Please see below. perhaps I am doing something incorrectly with the User fields? A simple input field shows up with no values instead of a select box.
here is what I added:

Comment: inspector: {
  type: String,
  autoform: {
   type: "selectize",
   options: function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({},fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}).map(function(c){
     var optionsArray = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      optionsArray[i] = {};
      optionsArray[i].label = c[name][i];
      optionsArray[i].value = c[name][i];
     }
     return optionsArray;
    })[0];
   },
   defaultValue: function(){
    return "Choose a User";
   },
  }
 },

Answer (score 0):

Really not answering but rather just giving a better visual of the code I added. I am getting an input box but not a select box. There is nothing inside the input. Here is what I added:

```js
inspector: {
  type: String,
  autoform: {
    type: "selectize",
    options: function() {
      return Meteor.users.find({}, fields: {
        emails: 1,
        profile: 1
      }).map(function(c) {
        var optionsArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
          optionsArray[i] = {};
          optionsArray[i].label = c[name][i];
          optionsArray[i].value = c[name][i];
        }
        return optionsArray;
      })[0];
    },
    defaultValue: function() {
      return "Choose a User";
    },
  }
},
```

Just curious what I got wrong.

Comment: I do get a select box now, but with no optionsNo console errors.

Comment: are you sure your collections has name as the attribute or is it username? if it is username it needs to be c[username]. if it is nested then c[nest][nest][0] like that.....

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I did not have name as an attribute. I did have firstName though. I tried both ways with that and no luck.

Comment: Please post the query in mongo db that gives the right result in mongo